# HTML- how do I specify the layout of input & span tags?

Tags: html, page-layout

On my website, I 'Save' button, which opens up a dialog box when clicked. The dialog box displays some information about the page being saved, and I have also just added a checkbox to allow the user to specify that they want this page to be the 'Home' page for the site. i.e. after checking the box, and clicking the 'Save' button on the dialog, the page that they're currently viewing will be set as the 'Home' page, so that whenever they click the 'Home' button on the site, they will be taken to this page rather than the default page.

This feature currently works, and I am now just trying to tidy up the presentation/ layout so that it is consistent with the rest of the dialog box.

The HTML is:

```
<div data-ng-show="layout.style == 'grid'">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <label data-i18n="Direction:"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{layout.direction}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <label data-i18n="Homepage:"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="homepageCheckbox" type="checkbox"
                ng-model="checkboxModel">
            <span data-i18n="Set this page as the home page"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason, the layout of the checkbox and description that I've added for it are not the same as everything else that is displayed on the dialog box:

[image: Screenshot of dialog box]

I was expecting the checkbox & description to be displayed inline with the 'Homepage' label, like all of the other items are... I'm guessing that the reason that this has been displayed on a new line is possibly because the width of the text is too long for the dialog box?

How can I specify that I want the checkbox & description text to be displayed in line with the 'Homepage' label, & with the other non-label elements displayed, even if it takes up two lines to do this?

**Edit**

I tried the suggestions given in the answers- and while this resolved the 'column' issue with the layout, it hasn't resolved the 'row' issue- i.e. the text is now confined to the correct column, but for some reason, it still appears to be displayed on a separate row to the label:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have 12 column layout but are using 14 column instructions in last row.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <label data-i18n="Homepage:"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 checkbox"> <!-- should be col-sm-8 -->
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="homepageCheckbox" type="checkbox"
                ng-model="checkboxModel">
            <span data-i18n="Set this page as the home page"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

So overall try this:

```
<div data-ng-show="layout.style == 'grid'">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <label data-i18n="Direction:"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{layout.direction}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <label data-i18n="Homepage:"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 checkbox">
        <input name="homepageCheckbox" type="checkbox"
                ng-model="checkboxModel">
        <span data-i18n="Set this page as the home page"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave this a go, and it has resolved the original issue- the checkbox & description text are now in line with the other 'non-label' elements of the dialog, and displayed on two rows... however for some reason, they are displayed one row below the 'Homepage' label- i.e. they are not in line with it... any ideas why this is?

Comment: Ah, it seems that was because I had an additional `<label class="checkbox">` tag inside the `<div class...>`

Comment: @someone2088 good job finding that out. I will also edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have given `col-sm-4` to label's parent div and `col-sm-10` to checkbox's parent div.

Bootstrap divided the page into 12 columns only. so sum of those two div's columns should not exceed 12. Make checkbox's parent div class to `col-sm-8` as you have given to direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- I did this, and it has sorted the issue with the columns- the checkbox & text are now in line with the other 'non-label' elements of the page, however for some reason, this has put the checkbox & description one row lower than the label, and not in line... How would I get them to be displayed on the same row?

Comment: thats because bootstrap's checkbox class has margin-top of 10px; override that to 0px

Comment: .checkbox {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

Comment: can you inspect the element an see whether it is overridden by something else

Comment: or else give important and check .checkbox { margin-top: 0px !important; }

Comment: When I inspect the element, it doesn't appear to be overwritten by anything else... it just shows the markup as I have posted it...

Comment: It seems that was because I had an additional `<label class="checkbox">` tag inside the <div class...>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-ng-show="layout.style == 'grid'">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <label data-i18n="Direction:"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{layout.direction}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <label data-i18n="Homepage:"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="homepageCheckbox" type="checkbox"
                ng-model="checkboxModel">
            <span data-i18n="Set this page as the home page"></span>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```